# Replace old value with new value in datagrid

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, datagrid

My datagrid consist of 3 columns. If the user edit the 1st cell in the "Qty" column (e.g from 1 to 2), then the 1st cell of "Price" column will double as value (e.g from 5 to 10). How do i do that?

```
    Qty | Description | Price

    1   |   apple     |  5
    1   |   cherry    |  2
    1   |   orange    |  4
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider();
var tempValue:Number;

var col1:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("Qty");
grid.addColumn(col1);
col1.dataField = "Qty";
col1.editable = true;
var col2:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("Denumire");
grid.addColumn(col2);
col2.dataField = "Denumire";
col2.editable = false;
var col3:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("Gramaj");
grid.addColumn(col3);
col3.dataField = "Gramaj";
col3.editable = false;
var col4:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("Pret");
grid.addColumn(col4);
col4.dataField = "Pret";
col4.editable = false;

grid.dataProvider = dp;
grid.editable = true;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("meniu.xml"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var xml:XML = new XML(loader.data);
    var itemList:XMLList = xml..item;
    var len:int = itemList.length();
    for (var i:int=0; i < len; i++)
    {
        dp.addItem({Qty:"1",
         Denumire:itemList[i].denumire,
         Gramaj:itemList[i].gramaj,
         Pret:itemList[i].pret});
    }
    grid.addEventListener(DataGridEvent.ITEM_EDIT_END, itemEditPreEnd, false, 100);
    grid.addEventListener(DataGridEvent.ITEM_EDIT_END, itemEditPostEnd, false, -100);

    calculateTotal();
}

function itemEditPreEnd(e:DataGridEvent):void
{
    var myGrid:DataGrid = e.target as DataGrid;
    var field:String = e.dataField;
    var row:Number = Number(e.rowIndex);
    if (myGrid != null)
    {
        if (field == "Qty")
        {
            tempValue = myGrid.dataProvider.getItemAt(row)[field];
        }
    }
}

function itemEditPostEnd(e:DataGridEvent):void
{
    var myGrid:DataGrid = e.target as DataGrid;
    var field:String = e.dataField;
    var row:Number = Number(e.rowIndex);
    if (myGrid != null)
    {
        if (field == "Qty")
        {
            var newValue:Number = myGrid.dataProvider.getItemAt(row)[field];
            var prevValue = myGrid.dataProvider.getItemAt(row).Pret;
            if (newValue != tempValue)
            {
                var replacedValue:Number =  prevValue * newValue;
                //trace(replacedValue)
                //code will go here
                calculateTotal();
            }
        }
    }
}

function calculateTotal():void
{
    var result:Number = 0;
    var len:Number = dp.length;
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        result +=  Number(dp.getItemAt(i).Pret);
    }
    total.text = result.toString();
```

Comment: I found something about editField(index:uint, dataField:String, data:Object). Is this what i am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere you need to track what the price per unit is. Maybe add another (editable?) column for this. Any time you change the quantity, it should multiply the quantity by price per unit and put that value into price. Then whenever the qty is changed, it also calculates the total for that item based off the price per unit, and then updates the total for all items.

I'm not familiar with the `DataGrid` class you're using, but I'd modify your function to get both the Qty value and the Price per unit value.

Where your line `// code goes here` is, you'd want to multiply Qty * PricePerUnit, and assign that value to PriceTotal for the same line.

If you want to do this in a hacky, backwards way in order to avoid adding a Price per unit column...

```
price = (price / prevValue) * newValue;
```

...would get you the number, as long as the price was right to begin with.

Comment: I don't see how that will help me. There is no method property that will come in handy?

Comment: I need to edit my answer...you're not dealing with ordinary Arrays but with a different class.